# Choose page for figure

Tags: floats, thesis, fullpage

I'm writing a thesis and have a few full-page figures that I've stuffed in the appendix while I write. I'm getting close to finishing and need to get them into the relevant chapter. TeX places everything beautifully without the big figures involved so I really just want to slap them in between 2 pages that are already looking good.

What I'm asking is: Is there a way to command a full-page figure to "create a page for yourself at the nearest / next page break"? so it doesn't change all of the floats already involved around the text.

I've played around with a few suggestions already on here but none seem to be working exactly as I need them too. [p] has come the closest, but likes to throw them all to the end of the chapter.

I would post some code but I'm willing to change to anything that will work so I'm not too fussed with modifying mine to work.

Cheers

Comment: put the float just before the place you want it to appear and then put `\clearpage` at the point that latex anyway breaks the page, then the float will appear at that page break.

Comment: I did try this and it was almost there. The issue is that the content above the figures is still being fiddled with so it needs to be a dynamic.

Comment: just leave out the `\clearpage` until the document is finished.

Comment: a full page figure with `[p]` should come at the next page break unless you already have pending figures to be placed on a text page (which need to be output first)

Comment: Use \afterpage{\clearpage} from the afterpage package.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'm glad you have faith in my packages:-)

Comment: @JohnKormylo Do you want to write an answer or do you have a dupe at hand?

Comment: @johannes_B - I was hoping for an MWE so I could test it first.